# How NVL function work in oracle internally

Tags: oracle

Any one can please explain this query executing internally.

```
 SELECT NVL(CELL.PERSONAL_NUMBER,
  (SELECT DTL.MSISDN_NUMBER
  FROM TABLE_DTL DTL
  WHERE DTL.MSISDN_DTL_ID=CELL.MSISDN_ID
  AND DTL.IS_ACTIVE      =CELL.IS_ACTIVE
  AND CELL.IS_ACTIVE     ='Y'
  )) AS NMS_NUMBER
FROM TABLE_1 prem,
  TABLE_CELL CELL
WHERE PREM.allocated_to=CELL.ENT_ORG_ID
AND PREM.mobile_number =12032456
AND PREM.id     =CELL.id
AND PREM.IS_ACTIVE     =CELL.IS_ACTIVE
AND PREM.IS_ACTIVE     ='Y'
AND PREM._ID     =18;
```

please explain this query in detail.

Comment: I want to know , how this query internally executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst we can't tell exactly how NVL is implemented under the hood since the code is proprietary, we know that NVL always executes both parameters passed in.

You might not think this has any impact, especially if you're using literal values (e.g. `nvl(col1, 'value')`), it can have implications if you're using functions in the 2nd parameter - they'll always be executed, as you can see from the below test case:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;

create or replace function test_fn
return number
is
begin
  return test_seq.nextval;
end;
/

select nvl(1, test_fn()) test_1
from   dual;

    TEST_1
----------
         1

select nvl(null, test_fn()) test_2
from   dual;

    TEST_2
----------
         2
```

Note how the result is 2, and not 1? This indicates that the sequence has been called twice - once for each function call.

`COALESCE`, on the other hand, does perform short-circuiting; it won't process any of the parameters past the first non-null parameter, like so:

```
select coalesce(1, test_fn()) test_3
from   dual;

    TEST_3
----------
         1

select coalesce(null, test_fn()) test_4
from   dual;

    TEST_4
----------
         3
```

See how the value for TEST_4 is 3, rather than 4? This indicates that the test_fn was only actioned once - when the value was null.

Answer (score 0):

We can't expain how NVL works. But, NVL replaces the empty string or null with a value . So if the `CELL.PERSONAL_NUMBER` is null or empty it get replaced by the following query output

```
SELECT DTL.MSISDN_NUMBER
  FROM TABLE_DTL DTL
  WHERE DTL.MSISDN_DTL_ID=CELL.MSISDN_ID
  AND DTL.IS_ACTIVE      =CELL.IS_ACTIVE
  AND CELL.IS_ACTIVE     ='Y'
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2048.htm\